# Java ArrayList adding element at nth position

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a question about `ArrayList`. When the arraylist in initialized the default size is 10.

When new elements are added to the arraylist, on reaching the arraylist size by 75%, say while adding the 7th value in arraylist will it expand the length.

I have an arraylist and I have added 3 values in it (say 10, 20 and 30). I am trying to add the next value at the 10th index but its throwing `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Why it was not allowed to add the values using that index value?

Comment: Can you edit the message and add your code please?

Comment: The capacity is there only for performance reasons. It is introduced because resizing the internal array everytime an element is added would slow things down. The default capacity is fine in most cases. You should only pass another value as capacity if you know something about the possible size forehand, for instance, if the array will become very large.

Answer (score 0):

The default *capacity* is 10, not the size. The size of a new `ArrayList` is 0. If there are only 3 elements in the list, then you can't insert something at index 10 because that index is beyond the size of the list.

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-):

> **Throws:**
>
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())

Answer (score 0):

When we create a ArrayList the internal array has the size 10. 
But their is also a element in ArrayList called int size, its value is 0 and only increments on adding elements to the arraylist. 
The same 'size' attribute is used when we call the method size().

Now if we try to add at an element at 10th index and the 'size' attribute is still 3, check is done as below

```
if (index > size || index < 0) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException;
```

Hence you get the Exception.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. understood now.

Comment: Good Explanation @Phani Kumar. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because the `add` method expands the `List` by calling `ensureCapacityInternal` see here

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}
```

while the `add(index, element)` method does not expand the `List` if the index is out of bound already.

```
  /**
 * Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this
 * list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and
 * any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).
 *
 * @param index index at which the specified element is to be inserted
 * @param element element to be inserted
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
 */
public void add(int index, E element) {
    rangeCheckForAdd(index);

    ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
    System.arraycopy(elementData, index, elementData, index + 1,
                     size - index);
    elementData[index] = element;
    size++;
}
```

This is the default behavior. [Source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java)

Answer (score 0):

Size of the ArrayList, not 10 when you create a ArrayList object with a default value. `10 is the size of Array backing` the list which is `Object[] elementData`. `Size` of the list still `returns 0` if you haven't added any element. So, if tried to set an index with greater than the size it will throw an exception. Below method calls from the `ArrayList#set()`

```
private void rangeCheck(int index) {
    if (index >= size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
}
```